# Populate Dropdown and other fields based on text box value in Struts2 and Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, struts2

I am using Struts 2 for my application. I want to update Dropdown and other three feilds based on Text box onblur action.? I am clear how to make ajax call. but i don't know how to populate multiple feilds from custom object return. The Objects will be 
1. List of Workers - how to build the Select Dropdown ht

On selection of Worker
Populate 
1. Salary Object Values in 3 Textboxes.

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026542/get-json-data-from-struts/13527598#13527598

Answer (score 0):

basically you have many choices.
First is to send like JSON data from your action class and fill the drop down and other fields from your action using Jquery/DOJO , plain java-script or any other JS framework of your choice.

If you want something out of the box can use [Struts2-Jquery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/)

Here is a small code populating drop-down based on the value entered by user on the first drop-down/text-box.

```
dropdownreset(document.getElementById("district_"));
        var selectedState = document.getElementById("stateList_");
        var statedata = selectedState.options[selectedState.selectedIndex].value;
        var formInput='state='+statedata;       
        $.getJSON('search/dropDownRenderer',formInput,function(data) {
            //$('.result').html('' + data.districts + '');
            $.each(data.districts,function(index, value){
            var districtid = document.getElementById("district_");
            var option=new Option(value,value);
            try{
                districtid.add(option);
            }
            catch(e){
                districtid.appendChild(option);
            }
            });
            });
```

So we are filling state and based on which district values are getting populated.In Action class we are sending back District list as JSON.So i believe in your case along with drop down values you can send other 2 fields as JSON data and let Jquery handle this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use the [Struts2 Jquery Plugin](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=Struts2%20Jquery%20Plugin&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDkQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/&ei=rvP-TsGrAcOzrAeuwM3vDw&usg=AFQjCNFgY6KtGJr_7jmyDla6N6NQ5qantQ). Then I have an answer to what you really want.

You can use <sj:select> with reloadTopics and publish those topics on the onblur event of the <s:textfield>. <sj:select> also takes the formId of the form to be submitted to the reloadTopics url.

[Here is a related example.](http://www.onlinexamples.com/showfullexample.action?idexamples=48&title=Dependent%20Select%20-%20Dependent%20Dropdowns%20-%20Triple%20Select%20Using%20Jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, will help you in Struts 2.0.14 with jsonplugin-0.32.jar.

struts.xml:

```
<struts>
     <package name="example" extends="json-default">
        <action name="HelloWorld" class="example.HelloWorld"  >
            <result type="json" />
        </action>
              <action name="HelloWorld1" class="example.HelloWorld"  >
            <result name="success" >example/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

action class Helloworld.java:

```
package prabhakar;

import glb.DB;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Prabhakar
 */
public class HelloWorld  {


    private List<StateMaster> stateList= new ArrayList<StateMaster>();
    private List<RegnMaster> regnList= new ArrayList<StateMaster>();

    private Integer stateId;
    public Integer getStateId()
    {
    return this.stateId;
    }
    public void setStateId(Integer stateId)
    {
    this.stateId=stateId;
    }
    public List<StateMaster> getStateList() {
        return stateList;
    }

    public void setStateList(List<StateMaster> stateList) {
        this.stateList = stateList;
    }
     public void setRegnList(List<RegnMaster> regnList) {
        this.regnList = regnList;
    }
    public List<RegnMaster> getRegnList() {
        return regnList;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {

        stateList=DB.getStateData()//
        if(stateId !=null)
          {
         regnList=DB.getRegnByStateId(stateId);
          }

        //setMessage(getText(MESSAGE));
        return "success";
    }

    /**
     * Provide default valuie for Message property.
     */

}
```

You can directly call HelloWorld.action to view the JSON data or else you can bind the JSON data to a form element below.

JSP page HelloWorld.jsp:

```
  /*
     Prabhakar
  */

<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>

<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<script>
<%@include file="../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"%>
</script>
    <html>

<!-- JavaScript Plugins -->
  <script>
       function getLoad(){


       var stateId = $('#state').val();

$.getJSON('HelloWorld.action', {'stateId': stateId},
    function(data) {

           var divisionList = (data.regnList);

                var options = $("#regn");
                options.find('option')
    .remove()
    .end();
     options.append($("<option />").val("-1").text("--Select--"));
$.each(divisionList, function() {

    options.append($("<option />").val(this.regnId).text(this.regnName));
});
    }
);}
   </script>

<!-- jQuery-UI Dependent Scripts -->

    <body>
        State List <s:select name="stateId" list="stateList" id="state" listKey="stateId" onchange="getLoad()" listValue="stateName" headerKey="0" headerValue="--select--" />
        Regn List <s:select name="regnId"  list="regnList" listKey="regnId" id="regn" listValue="regnName" headerKey="0" headerValue="--select--" />
    </body>
</html>
```