# struts 2 + json

Tags: json, struts2

I want to know that if Struts 2 core jar must be in sync with the Struts2-Json-Plugin jar. because when i am returning 'SUCCESS' from a method in Action class then exception is occurring . ihave declared result type as 'json' in my xml as

```
<result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult"/>
```

and the exception i am getting is

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.get(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:166)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:348)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:253)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
```

i am using struts2-core-2.0.11.jar and my struts.xml is

```
<action name="editEmployee" class="myaction.AddEmployeeAction" method="getValue">
      <result name="success" type="json" />
</action>
```

and my action is

```
public class AddEmployeeAction extends ActionSupport implements ParameterAware {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private EmployeeDaoImp empdao;
private Map parameters;

public EmployeeDaoImp getEmpdao() {
    return empdao;
}

public void setEmpdao(EmployeeDaoImp empdao) {
    this.empdao = empdao;
}

public String getValue() throws Exception
{
    //JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    String query = getParameterValue("selChar");
    List<String> names = empdao.getData(query);
    /*for (String name : names) {
        jsonArr.add(name);
    }*/
    jsonObject.put("namesList", names);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

}

Comment: what version of `struts2` you are using? Can u post the Action and your `struts.xml`?

Comment: see i have changed my question and i am using struts2-json-plugin-2.1.8.jar for json.

Comment: You should definitely upgrade to the latest JARs. 2.0.11 is ancient.

Comment: try this.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026542/get-json-data-from-struts/13527598#13527598][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026542/get-json-data-from-struts/13527598#13527598

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S2 plugin versions must match the S2 version; plugins use mechanisms provided by struts2-core.

While a plugin *may* work with a different version of core, it will never be *tested* like that, so unless you provide your own test harness, there's no way to know what the behavior will be if you start mixing and matching at random. You should *not* mix and match.

Comment: thanks @Dave..... it all was the game of jar.... when i put the same version jars... then things worked out for me... Cheers