# Which version of jquery and json do I need for struts2.1.6?

Tags: jquery, json, struts2

I'm obliged to work by **Struts2.1.6**. I downloaded it from the archive. I need to work by **struts2-jquery-plugin and struts2-json-plugin** for my project. But I don't find any plugin of json in the downloaded version. Also, I don't know which version of jquery plugin would work with struts2.1.6. Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: Struts is a server-side MVC framework for *Java*. jQuery is a function library for *Javascript*. JSON is a *Javascript* data structure notation. Thus, Struts has little if anything to do with jQuery, and only has anything to do with JSON inasmuch as you can serialize data from your application to JSON (usually by creating a View that outputs JSON data).

Comment: @BrianDriscoll I assume he's referring to the struts jquery plugin...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646372/struts-2-json/11652917#11652917

Comment: Yes, I mean struts2-jquery-plugin and struts2-json-plugin. I'm going to do an edit.

Comment: @nmc That response only applies to official S2 plugins, which the jQuery plugin isn't; the JSON plugin is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the 2.1.6 JSON plugin; you should *not* mix-and-match official plugins.

I'm not aware of any major S2 version issues with the plugin, although it's been some time since I've used it with that old of an S2 version. The jQuery plugin 2.3 version works with 2.1.8, I'd be a *little* surprised if it didn't work with 2.1.6 as well; IIRC it's just components, etc.

I'd probably just try one of the more recent versions and see if it works. Otherwise consider just writing plain jQuery/JavaScript rather than fighting with an old version of the jQuery plugin.

Comment: Well, it seems to me I will try to convince them to upgrade the version of S2. Because I confess, the things which are waiting for me are difficult too and I have no previous experience with JQuery and there's still no enough time to deal with. Thank you, for your answers. I upvote the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

JSon is just a data format. You don't need to download it. And jQuery 1.4.2 was the version it was designed for.