# struts2 Async Action

Tags: struts2, servlet-3.0

Looking to use Struts2 with Serlvet 3.0 Async support.

My first approach was to just handle to writing to the outputstream in the action and returning null.  This however returns with a 404 "resource not available".  I am attempting to adapt a Bosh servlet inside of a struts action, using ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware interfaces to inject the response.

I am using the struts filter dispatcher.  Not entirely sure if this is doable,but would be sure happy if someone else has managed to get async to work within a struts action.  Perhaps here is an AsyncResult type or someother magic to make this work.

Comment: Check this [link][1]. It may help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026542/get-json-data-from-struts/13527598#13527598

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the struts filter allows async.  Here's what that looks like in the web.xml file:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
```

Then from within an Action obtain the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` and use the `AsyncContext` as you would within a servlet:

```java
public String execute() {
  HttpServletRequest req = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
  HttpServletResponse res = ServletActionContext.getResponse();

  final AsyncContext asyncContext = req.startAsync(req, res);
  asyncContext.start(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        // doing some work asynchronously ...
      }
      finally {
        asyncContext.complete();
      }
    }
  });

  return Action.SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? I tested this with JMeter and there are not any improvement in performance and behaves like a sync action. This seems not work :(

Comment: Yes.  In my use case the action was sending an email to potentially many destinations and I didn't want to hold up the response rendering until all the emails had been sent.  Using the `AsyncContext` allowed the action to return immediately to the user while continuing to send emails.

Comment: Maybe you used `ExecAndWait interceptor`! As I studied, `AsyncContext` does not return immediately to the user but returns current thread to pool and runs async code in another thread. When completed, it get another thread from pool to send response back to user. i.e. in user point-of-view it's synchronous not asynchronous. I just tested your above code and a `Thread.sleep` in it with JMeter; I could not see any difference in result when usres, threads and connections exceed their maximum.

Comment: Interesting.  Yes, I just looked at the code and it differs from what is shown above: we're calling `asyncContext.complete()` right away within the `try` block and then performing the actual work (and not using a `finally` block at all).