# Reducing execution time for code

Tags: java, performance, optimization

I am generating web based invoices using struts2 for customers and while sending invoice i am sending email and sms to user.After generating invoice I am redirecting page to generated invoice page.

My code is like below

```
public generateInvoice(Invoice invoce)
{
   int i=DB.insert(invoice);
   if(i==1)
   {
      DB.sendEmail(invoice);
      Db.smsInvoiceIinvoice);
   }
     redirect to generatedInvoice page
}
```

Where DB is object of class to insert data and to email and sms invice.
My problem is while generating invoice sending email and sending sms is taking too much time.

Another way I thought is that after generation invoice I will be redirect to generated invoice page from there i will send sms and email to user, but problem is that if user will immediately click on another page link then there may be problem.

How can I reduce this time?

Comment: You may process `sendEmail` and `smsInvoice` concurrently.

Comment: any example or code link  ?

Comment: This do the trick for you.. struts2 support async actions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844797/struts2-async-action

Comment: @mhasan LOL ! That's new to me :P

Comment: Both sending email and sending sms are slow and unreliable operations.  You should separate the process of actually sending.  Mark the invoice as needing to be emailed/sms'd and delegate to another procedure.

Comment: @ddyer Is there any way that invoice is saved to db then it will return to generated invoice page and in between it will send mail and sms. without affecting the rest user task .

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should answer is: Could `sending email` and `sending sms` be done in parallel ? If this is true then you can create a thread for each one and let them be executed together. After finishing both threads your action is done. In this way the total time for execution will be the time of longest thread.

I think the main problem is that, the user will just see an annoying browser wait ststus while the email and sms are sent. You can use the Struts 2 execute and wait interceptor ( http://struts.apache.org/docs/execute-and-wait-interceptor.html).

> The ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor is great for running long-lived actions
>   in the background while showing the user a nice progress meter. This
>   also prevents the HTTP request from timing out when the action takes
>   more than 5 or 10 minutes.

Please note that this interceptor will not reduce the execution time, but make it user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

These time consuming email and sms tasks can be placed in separate queues and use multi-threads to process them parallely . Please check out the producer/consumer pattern: https://dzone.com/articles/producer-consumer-pattern