# Java Reflection for capturing parameters from the client in RESTful web services?

Tags: java, ajax, rest, reflection, struts2-jquery

I am using Struts 2-REST plugin for web services for my web app. It uses backbone.js to retrieve and display data from the services. However, I am struggling on how to capture the parameters from the collection.fetch() method to the server-side (Java). It is somehow similar how it is applied in AJAX.

For example:

Example #1

```
fetchStudents : function() {
    this.fetch({
      data : {
        packet : JSON.stringify({
          type : "retrieveAllStudents",
          data : {}
        })
      },
      type : 'POST',
      success : function(collection, response, options) {
        console.log('SUCCESS: all students fetched');
      }
    });
  }
```

Example #2:

```
fetchStudentById : function(studentId) {
    this.fetch({
      data : {
        packet : JSON.stringify({
          type : "retrieveStudentById",
          data : {
              studentId : studentId
            }
        })
      },
      type : 'POST',
      success : function(collection, response, options) {
        console.log('SUCCESS: student#' + studentId + ' fetched');
      }
    });
  }
```

Based on the examples above, parameter `type` refers to name of method to be called, whilst `data` is for the parameter/s of the method to be called.

For example# 1, it will be calling method `retrieveAllStudents()`; and example #2 will be calling `retrieveStudentById(studentId)` method.

Would it be advisable if I will use Java Reflections? Based on my research, its performance is slow, isn't it? If any, are there alternatives for Reflections?

Comment: I believe you have two variations while getting the students, the first one is to get all students and the second one is for a specific student id. So you should have two different URIs for these, /students and /students/{id} respectively.

Comment: How would I use those URIs without scrapping off the fetch() methods as the examples above? I believe in backbone.js, you are only allowed to use one URI (for collections).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get JSON data from struts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026542/get-json-data-from-struts)